# Passing an additional variable in respond_to method after create controller is successful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to pass the view controller a params that it can consume after a successful create event has been triggered. Right now at the end of the create event I have the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @link.save
    format.html { redirect_to @link, :notice => 'Link was successfully created.', :first => 'true' }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
  end
end
```

I was trying to pass a 'first' parameter in the 3rd line down, but I'm either not calling it correctly on the view page or I'm not setting it correctly here. Below is the code I'm using to try and call it on the view page:

```
params[:first]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Quatz's answer won't work. Instance variables will not be available after you send redirect_to, which is because redirect_to actually returns 302 back to the browser with a redirect Location header so that the browser will be redirected. So the instance created in previous request won't be available at all.

There could be two solutions to your problem:

1. Use session. session[:first] = true before you call the redirect_to. After that, you can access the value using session[:first]
2. Modify your redirect_to to something like

   redirect_to link_path(@link, :first => 'true'), :notice => 'Link was successfully created.'}

using the named routes you can pass in parameters.

Comment: Thanks Shanison. Your second option uses a query string so when a user bookmarks it, the query string also gets saved. The fist option worked great though! I just cleared out the session after the view page had rendered and it works like a temporary indicator.

Comment: Hi Adam, if you don't want to query string to be booked marked, then I guess session is the only choice that I can think of. Since you don't need to persist the data through out the whole session, using flash would be a better choice. redirect_to @link, :notice => 'Link was successfully created.'}, :flash => {:first => 'true'}

Answer (score 0):

You can use instance variable in such case. Create an instance variable @first like this.

```
@first = params[:first]
```

In your view file use this.

```
<%= @first.attributes %>
```